# Is it ok to alter shared memory before unlinking and replacing it?

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have a scenario where process A opens and writes some shared memory segment "foo" and process B opens and reads (only reads) this memory. Whenever A is restarted, it wipes out shared memory files (this is to prevent stale ones to linger and for B to mistakenly open a stale one).

The problem is that if I restart A, I basically invalidate the shared memory "foo" which B is using and need to restart B. I want to get around this as follows:

Whenever A starts up, it looks for "foo", but before calling shm_unlink("foo") it writes something to a header in "foo" - some flag - which says it is no longer valid. Then it calls shm_unlink("foo") followed by recreating it via shm_open with O_CREAT. B would check this flag before trying to rely on the contents of mem_mapped "foo", and if it finds that the flag is invalid it reloads (i.e. waits a couple seconds and then searches the file system for "foo" again and memory maps it).

What I'm worried about, though, is that if I shm_unlink("foo") and recreate it, that maybe B can no longer count on the stale "foo" to even read the validity flag! Is this approach unsafe in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's fine. The shared memory segments are reference counted. When you call shm_unlink(), you're only removing the name of the segment, not the content.

The content is removed when the last process that have it mapped unmaps it by calling munmap(), and have closed(by calling close()) the descriptor returned by shm_open. (Normally the descriptor should be closed after it has been mmap()'ed anyway)

So the original memory segment in your process B is valid after process A called shm_unlink, and will be destroyed when process B munmap()s it if process B is the last process to do so, and doing another shm_open() will give you the new segment that process A created.

Just be sure to handle race conditions, your process B might open the old segment again if process A isn't finished with it, or you might try to open the segment before process A has created or initialized it again.

Comment: Should not we use a synchronization between processA and processB to ensure that B is not reading a partially updated memory ? Or a really shared memory operations atomics ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta You certainly need synchronization on accessing the shared memory.